# React Native/Expo Web: Input Focus Triggers Pull-to-Refresh (iOS Safari)

Tags: react-native, webview, expo, mobile-safari, pull-to-refresh

I'm encountering a specific behavior with pull-to-refresh in a React Native application running on Expo Router within iOS Safari (mobile web). Here's the scenario:

- I have a ScrollView component containing content and an input field.
- Setting `touch-action: none` on the `ScrollView` successfully disables pull-to-refresh when the input field is not focused.
- However, when the input field gains focus, Safari Mobile automatically adjusts the view to ensure the input is fully visible. This focus-induced scroll seems to trigger the pull-to-refresh gesture unintentionally.

## Expected Behavior:

I want to prevent pull-to-refresh entirely, regardless of input focus, while maintaining smooth scrolling functionality.

## Tried Solutions:

Using touch-action: none on the ScrollView (works when input is not focused).

## Questions:

- Has anyone encountered this specific issue where input focus triggers pull-to-refresh in React Native/Expo web on iOS Safari?
- Are there recommended approaches to handle focus scrolling while maintaining disabled pull-to-refresh on iOS devices using React Native/Expo web?

**Additional Information:**

React Native version 0.73.4
Expo version 50.0.11